# Should you retopologize a "low poly" character?

Tags: modeling, animation, armature, topology

[image]

The picture above is a low poly style character found on google. My problem is this thing looks a pain to animate, and I don't really know if you should retopologize this. You will probably end up with more faces than the base model.

If you think about it there's not a lot of polygons to work on on joints and stuff so it would look logical for me to make a good retopology and bake the character for a normal/ambien occlusion map to get that look but work with a real normal topology on the back. Do I see it right?

I'm not sure if this is a good place to ask this question, sorry if it is not.

Comment: imho it all depends on the intended movements... the more natural it should appear, the more polygons you need... not impossible but difficult, yes.

Comment: My question is more about how does low poly art actually looks like behind the scenes. Cause animating with what we see on the image i posted i think is hard.